# Good way to do a "switch" in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, switch-statement

I'm experimenting with an updated build system at work; currently, I'm trying to find a good way to set compiler & flags depending on the target platform.

What I would like to do is something like

```
switch $(PLATFORM)_$(BUILD_TYPE)
  case "Linux_x86_release"
     CFLAGS = -O3
  case "Linux_x86_debug"
     CFLAGS = -O0 -g
  case "ARM_release"
     CC = armcc
     AR = armlink
     CFLAGS = -O2 -fx
     ...
```

which is not supported by GNU Make. Now, my first thought was to just do

```
-include $(PLATFORM)_$(BUILD_TYPE)
```

which is a pretty decent solution, however, it makes it hard to get an overview of what differs between files, not to mention that I'm looking forward to writing & maintaining a good 60-80 files, each containing a set of variable definitions.

Does anyone happen to know a better way to accomplish this? I.e. setting a set of flags and other options based on another variable?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Switching to a system which does it for you (automake/autoconf) may be simpler...

Comment: My use-case is actually that I have a makefile-based system that builds a large set of components, of which some have configure scripts that need to be driven properly. The build system keeps things separate per output target with an $(arch)-like string that can't be passed to config.sub, so I need a case statement that converts our $(arch) to the value of --host to be passed to the configure script. We actually get the $(arch) from something like `-include $(PLATFORM)_$(BUILD_TYPE)` at the top of the build system.

Answer (score 39):

How about:

```
CFLAGS_Linux_x86_release        = -O3
CFLAGS_Linux_x86_debug          = -O0 -g


CFLAGS  = ${CFLAGS_${PLATFORM}_${BUILD}}
```

Comment: Thank you, neat trick. Works also for Solaris makefiles, which allows me to use the same makefiles on Solaris and Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Configuring such parameters would be the task of a `configure` script.

That being said, you can look into the syntax for [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) and [conditional functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions). For example, you could try the following:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM)_$(BUILD_TYPE),Linux_x86_release)
    CFLAGS = -O3
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM)_$(BUILD_TYPE),Linux_x86_debug)
    CFLAGS = -O0 -g
endif
```

Comment: Yes, but this syntax is GNUmake-specific (the portable part of the makefile language is very small. Almost every non-trivial Makefile is non portable)

Comment: Well, either depend on gmake and use ifeq/endif, or depend on pmake and use #if/#endif, or depend on bmake and use .if/.endif, or depend on a Makefile-generator.

Answer (score 5):

The [Makefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Makefile) used by [git](https://git-scm.com) is a good example of a Makefile which does non-trivial configuration tasks in the Makefile itself (such as switching on the host type). It's actually quite readable and reasonably simple to use.

Comment: The stuff `ifeq`/`endif` has been moved to file [`config.mak.uname`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/config.mak.uname). Please update your answer and provide some examples. Cheers ;-) (Happy new year)

Comment: Eh, no, I'm not going to spend my time updating a six year old answer just because the Git developers decided to change their makefiles. I have funnier things to do. :)

Comment: Alright, I upvote your answer anyway. If someone wants to see the update, he/she can read my comment. However I would appreciate you take some pleasure updating your answers... Cheers and happy new year.

Comment: You should update the answer as it is pretty much link-only (in that if the link dies, there is no useful content)